EXCEPTION IN Deploying Safe Account
const deploySafe = async () => {
    try {
      const safeFactory1 = await SafeFactory.init({
        provider: RPC_URL,
        signer: OWNER_1_PRIVATE_KEY,
      });
      const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
        owners: [OWNER_1_ADDRESS],
        threshold: 1,
        // Optional params
      };

      if (safeFactory1) {
        /* This Safe is tied to owner 1 because the factory was initialized with the owner 1 as the signer. */
        const protocolKitOwner1 = await safeFactory1.deploySafe({
          safeAccountConfig,
        });

        const safeAddress = await protocolKitOwner1.getAddress();

        console.log("Your Safe has been deployed:");
        console.log(`https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/${safeAddress}`);
        console.log(`https://app.safe.global/sep:${safeAddress}`);
      }
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  };

At first deployment of fresh safe account, i get this error, but the safe account gets deployed tho, and i get the address also
Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32000, "message": "already known" }, payload={ "id": 22, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", }
But When i run the same function after the first attempt i get this error
Execution reverted: "Create2 call failed" (action="estimateGas", data="0x..", reason="Create2 call failed", transaction={ "data": "0x..", "from": "0x87cd12be2cf76239294D97Ea4978Ee9cC19Fd283", "to": "0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC" }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "Create2 call failed" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.1)

It's failing gas estimation because you are supplying the same arguments to GnosisSafeProxyFactory function
function createProxyWithNonce(
        address _singleton,
        bytes memory initializer,
        uint256 saltNonce
    ) 


(https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC#code)
. This results in creation of the same proxy contract address which already has code because of your previous deployment , so create2 is returning a address(0) which is then thrown due by the require statement
assembly {
            proxy := create2(0x0, add(0x20, deploymentData), mload(deploymentData), salt)
        }
require(address(proxy) != address(0), "Create2 call failed");



There are 2 contracts , proxy and singleton . A proxy contract stores all the state variables required by the singleton contract. A singleton contract is where all your logic/implementation lies . The first transaction goes through because a  fresh proxy contract is created and linked to a singleton .
when you are deploying for the second time with the same singleton address , its designed to throw because you have already linked a singleton to a proxy .

Can you suggest any changes to my code, which can fix this?

There is no fix , that's how it's designed . Changing OWNER_1_ADDRESS will allow you to redeploy during the second time but that may not be what you want .

Is there any way to know where an account already exists, so that I do not re-deploy it everytime and can also fetch the account to do transactions.
